# Android open camera with face features detection (mouth,lips,eyes,cheeks)

Tags: android, face-recognition, feature-detection

I am working on a project, in which i need to detect the facial features of someone,in real time, using the camera and be able to interact with those. For example, with a tap on the screen, the eye's area should become black.

I have done a lot of searching but nothing seems to fit.
I am either not searching in the right places either i don't understand fully the potential of what i find by searching.

I would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Google Mobile Vision Library. It is part of Google Play Services. It can detect:

1. left and right eye
2. left and right ear
3. left and right ear tip
4. base of the nose
5. left and right cheek
6. left and right corner of the mouth
7. base of the mouth

For further information, check out these links:

[developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/vision/android/face-tracker-tutorial)

[JournalDev](https://www.journaldev.com/15629/android-face-detection)

Note:-

JournalDev site states:

Add the following dependency inside the build.gradle file of your application.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.0.4'
```

Instead of `compile` you need to use `implementation` keyword here:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.0.4'
```